# Getting error error rejection promise of the file tried to fix it but its not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, redux

[image]code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-gates-svzfq

I am facing this issue. I have attached the code and error and CodeSandbox link.

Tried to fix the issue in various methods and ways but it's not fixing. I am not able to know why it's getting an error I don't understand the exact issue in the code. Could anyone help with the solution?

Unhandeld rejection promise [image: error]

```
  const isSupported = (file) => {
    let type = file?.type.split("/")[1];
    let allowedTypes = ["png", "jpg", "jpeg"];
    return allowedTypes.includes(type);
  };

  function ValidateSize(file) {
    var FileSize = file.files[0].size / 1024 / 1024; // in MiB
    const overSize = FileSize > 10;
    if (overSize) {
      alert("File size exceeds above 10MB");
    }
    return overSize;
  }
   
  function handleChange(e){
    if (ValidateSize(e.target)) {
    return;
    }
  
    if (isSupported(e.target.files[0])) {
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
  
    setFileList((prev) => ({...prev,fileList,img:url}));
    } else {
    alert("Only jpg/jpeg and png files are allowed!");
    }
  }
```

Comment: ValidateSize takes two parameters but you are only passing in one - so fileList is undefined.

Comment: @james I had tried that method also but not working

Comment: @james where is the exact issue

Comment: Take a look at the ant Upload code samples [here](https://ant.design/components/upload/#components-upload-demo-basic) your handleChange function should expect an "info" parameter not a javascript event.

Comment: @james the above validation & oversize not working

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned this is react stuff so the parameter being passed into handleChange is not a standard javascript event object.  It's specific to the library you are using ([Ant Design](https://ant.design/components/upload/#onChange)), so "e.target" isn't valid.  I've never used ant but assuming the rest of your code is correct here's what I'd try.

```js
  function handleChange(info) {
   
    const {file, fileList} = info;
  
    if (ValidateSize(file)) {
      return;
    }
  
    if (isSupported(file)) {
      window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
      setFileList((prev) => ({...prev,fileList,img:url}));
    } else {
      alert("Only jpg/jpeg and png files are allowed!");
    }
  }
```

Comment: I suggest moving the destructuring of `info` into the function parameter list, since you never use `info` for anything else. eg. `function handleChange({file, fileList})`

Comment: @3limin4t0r I considered it but I think some confusion was caused to OP initially by copying code that used destructured parameters and then "deleting the curly brackets", so I left it as a separate operation.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I am getting Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: @prohith You are still using `handleChange(e)`, then use `e.target`. Have you read the answer above? `handleChange` is not passed a native JavaScript event. Use `handleChange(info)` then use `info.file` to access the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line of the `ValidateSize` function assumes that the `file.files` is defined. But if you don't have any files in the event then it likely will not be.

```
    var FileSize = file.files?.[0].size / 1024 / 1024; // in MiB
```

Comment: that not working in codesandboox i had tried

Comment: https://ant.design/components/upload/#components-upload-demo-basic